# Which Ubuntu Version Will Work Best with 1.6MHz Dual Core Celeron N3050

Tags: cpu

It seems the 'formal'requirement for Ubuntu 20 is a 1.8GHz dual core Celeron.  For lightweight work (web browsing, file transfers, downloads) would a 1.6GHz dual processor be OK?

Comment: Any version will be fine.

Comment: This is why the Ubuntu installer includes a risk-free "Try Ubuntu" environment: So you can test your hardware and workflow thoroughly before making any decisions.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install   (applies to all *flavors* of Ubuntu too); also note the 20 or *year* based products are different to the 20.04 or *year.month* products.  Ubuntu Core 20 is a different system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for example.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  will suggest your specs are unlikely to be a good match for Ubuntu Desktop (but you didn't provide RAM, video RAM etc) but *flavors* may still be good.

Comment: Also note CPU *celeron* & marketing-speed are not good indications, eg. a `celeron 2ghz` I rarely used in QA-testing as the box was horrifically slow, worse than pentium 4, pentium M & others. A later `c2d-t6570` was better, so get specific details & all details when you check the system requirements (eg. does your box have `3D  Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB` ? etc ... the celeron box I mentioned didn't & it made a big difference!

Comment: I used to use an all-in-one with these processors you mentioned here and still have it with 20.04, has a max RAM limit on 3GB, I can barely watch YouTube without HD. It's almost wasting time and electricity. Well, in your case Celeron N3050 consumes only 1/10 of Core2Duo E7500 then it's not much waste of electricity. But a lot slower than 12 year-old machine. It's still Okay but not encouraging. Buy something else if you can.

Comment: Did you mean to write GHz? I don't think a 1.6 MHz CPU will work well with Ubuntu, if at all

Comment: @sammynorth how much RAM do you have? Do you have SSD is this computer? It seems that you mean  GHzs not MHzs, so I edited your question. Do you consider to run some flavor - like Lubuntu or MATE?